# Tcl regular expression string matching

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a list of strings like this one:

```
A/B/C/P/E
```

I want to use a regex to capture only up to

```
A/B/C/P
```

and ignore the trailing `/E`

I tried using:

```
set mystring {A/B/C/P/E}
regex -nocase -- {(.*)\/\S+} $myString match
puts $match
```

but

```
puts $match
```

prints

```
A/B/C/P/E
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match/avoid?  You want to get rid of the last instance of a forward slash followed by a single capital letter?  Just the substring `/E` specifically?

Comment: Hi CAustin, I need to get rid of the last / followed by a string (not necessarily just one letter, the string can be alphaneumeric, just numeric, just a letter, or a mix of alphanumeric and special characters.

Comment: Well, it's a bit strange; your regex seems to work just fine when I test it. http://regex101.com/r/pI3yN0 It might have something to do with your code and not the pattern itself.  Have you tried the same syntax with a much simpler regex that has little chance of failing?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a couple of things wrong actually.

1. You have a string named `$mystring`, but you are using `$myString` in your function.
2. The syntax for [`regexp`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm) is:

   ```
   regexp ?switches? exp string ?matchVar? ?subMatchVar subMatchVar ...?
   ```

   So you if you want the submatch, you need to use another variable.

Now, to make everything cleaner, you can use:

```
set myString {A/B/C/P/E}
regexp -- {(.*)/\S+} $myString -> match
puts $match
# => A/B/C/P
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/l8fCZjYX)

You don't need to escape the forward slash, and if you don't have character that have casing in your regex, you don't need the `-nocase` flag.

The whole match is stored in the variable named `->` and the first submatch in `match`.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative: split the string, take all but the last element, re-join the list:

```
% set mystring {A/B/C/P/E}
A/B/C/P/E
% set new [join [lrange [split $mystring /] 0 end-1] /]
A/B/C/P
```